# Fractional Sobolev norm of characteristic function of an interval?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus

Is there an explicit expression giving a fractional Sobolev norm of the characteristic function of some interval $I=[a,b)$?

I believe it is true that $\chi_{I} \in W^{s,1}(\mathbb{R})$ for $s < \frac 12$.

Comment: You can compute the double integral defining the norm and find that it belongs to $W^{s,p}$ for $s<1/p$. For $p=2$ you can also use the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

Up to some normalization, the Fourier transform of the characteristic function $\mathbf 1_I$ of a compact interval $I$ is 
$$
\widehat{\mathbf 1_I}(\xi)=\frac{\sin \xi}{\xi}.
$$
Obviously the function $\mathbf 1_I$ is in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ but also in $W^{s, 2}(\mathbb R)$ for any $s<1/2$ since for $0\le s<1/2$, we have
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\left\vert\frac{\sin \xi}{\xi}\right\vert^2 \vert \xi\vert^{2s}d\xi<+\infty.
$$
The index $1/2$ is sharp since
$
\int_{\vert \xi\vert\ge 1}\left\vert\frac{\sin \xi}{\xi}\right\vert^2 \vert \xi\vert d\xi=+\infty.
$

Comment: Is it possible to evaluate the $W^{s,2}$ norm though, or at least give a bound for it in terms of the measure of the interval or something related?

Comment: Yes. The norm is translation invariant so you may assume that $I=(-a,a)$. Now use dilations to relate the seminorn of any $u$ to that of $u_{\lambda} (x)=u(\lambda x)$.